# C++ - What does const represent here?

Tags: c++, constants

If I get a C++ statement as follows:

`double getPrice() const;`

What doesn `const` represent here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is for member functions (in classes or structs). It means that the method won't change the state of the instance it operates on (won't change any member variables for example).

Comment: Unless they were declared mutable

Comment: @Armen Tsirunyan: If they are declared mutable then technically they not part of the objects logical state.

Comment: I was complaining about the phrase "won't change any member variables for example"

Answer (score 3):

When you call nonstatic member functions, you always call it on some object, right? That object is passed (implicitly) as a parameter. For example, if GetPrice is the method of class X, then it has an implicit parameter of type `X&`. Then the method is const, the implicit argument is of type `const X`&, therefore the member function cannot change any data member of the object on which it was invoked, UNLESS the data member was declared `mutable`.

Answer (score 2):

It signifies that it will not change the members of the class as a side effect.

Answer (score 1):

`const` means that `getPrice()` won't modify instance fields, except those explicitly declared as `mutable`.

Comment: A binary dump is not guaranteed to be the same before and after.  The method is permitted to change members declared mutable.